# How do I convert multiple lists inside a list using Python?

Tags: python, join, nested-lists

I want to convert multiple lists inside a list? I am doing it with a loop, but each sub list item doesn't get a comma between it.

```
myList = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
myString = ''
for x in myList:
    myString += ",".join(x)
print myString
```

ouput:

```
a,b,c,da,b,c,d
```

desired output:

```
a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using a list comprehension where you will "flatten" your list of lists in to a single list, and then use the "join" method to make your list a string. The ',' portion indicates to separate each part by a comma.

```
','.join([item for sub_list in myList for item in sub_list])
```

*Note: Please look at my analysis below for what was tested to be the fastest solution on others proposed here*

Demo:

```
myList = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]
result = ','.join([item for sub_list in myList for item in sub_list])
```

output of result -> `a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d`

However, to further explode this in to parts to explain how this works, we can see the following example:

```
# create a new list called my_new_list
my_new_list = []
# Next we want to iterate over the outer list
for sub_list in myList:
    # Now go over each item of the sublist
    for item in sub_list:
        # append it to our new list
        my_new_list.append(item)
```

So at this point, outputting my_new_list will yield:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

So, now all we have to do with this is make it a string. This is where the `','.join()` comes in to play. We simply make this call:

```
myString = ','.join(my_new_list)
```

Outputting that will give us:

```
a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d
```

## Further Analysis

So, looking at this further, it really piqued my interest. I suspect that in fact the other solutions are possibly faster. Therefore, why not test it!

I took each of the solutions proposed, and ran a timer against them with a much bigger sample set to see what would happen. Running the code yielded the following results in increasing order:

1. *map: 3.8023074030061252*
2. *chain: 7.675725881999824*
3. *comprehension: 8.73164687899407*

So, the clear winner here is in fact the map implementation. If anyone is interested, here is the code used to time the results:

```
from timeit import Timer


def comprehension(l):
    return ','.join([i for sub_list in l for i in sub_list])


def chain(l):
    from itertools import chain
    return ','.join(chain.from_iterable(l))


def a_map(l):
    return ','.join(map(','.join, l))

myList = [[str(i) for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

print(Timer(lambda: comprehension(myList)).timeit())
print(Timer(lambda: chain(myList)).timeit())
print(Timer(lambda: a_map(myList)).timeit())
```

Comment: I would give an example that isn't a list comprehension for those unfamiliar with them so they can easily translate into the comprehension.

Comment: Agreed. I will expand the example.

Comment: and use the same variable names as the OP, so my_list -> myList

Comment: @KronoS Let me know what you think of the "exploded" explanation.

Comment: Agreed @Mathias711 I just made the necessary changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
from itertools import chain

myList = [['a','b','c','d'],['a','b','c','d']]

print(','.join(chain.from_iterable(myList)))

a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just join at both levels:

```
>>> ','.join(map(','.join, myList))
'a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d'
```

It's shorter and significantly faster than the other solutions:

```
>>> myList = [['a'] * 1000] * 1000
>>> from timeit import timeit

>>> timeit(lambda: ','.join(map(','.join, myList)), number=10)
0.18380278121490046

>>> from itertools import chain
>>> timeit(lambda: ','.join(chain.from_iterable(myList)), number=10)
0.6535200733309843

>>> timeit(lambda: ','.join([item for sub_list in myList for item in sub_list]), number=10)
1.0301431917067738
```

I also tried `[['a'] * 10] * 10`, `[['a'] * 10] * 100000` and `[['a'] * 100000] * 10` and it was always the same picture.

Comment: Oh I didn't even realize that you also added a timer. I just did the same. :) Very interesting results. +1

Comment: Hehe, I guess it's easy to miss, it's only 86% of my post :-P Anyway, good to see that you got similar timings and good to have timings in the accepted answer.

Comment: haha. Hey, that 14% was all it took to want me to start playing with the timings.

Comment: Did some more tests. For very small cases like `[['a','b'],['a','b']]`, your list comprehension wins.

Comment: Ah, yes, same here. But seems almost negligible. Using your input between our solutions, my timings were: `('comprehension', 1.1399926629965194), ('map', 1.3782716009882279)`. Was yours similar?

Comment: Yes, 1.46 for comprehension and 1.74 for map.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [['a','b','c','d'],[a','b','c','d']]
smyList = myList[0] + myList[1]
str1 = ','.join(str(x) for x in smyList)
print str1
```

output

```
a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d
```